# Writing java object into .csv

Tags: java, file, opencsv

I have the java class below:

```
class DeviceUser{
private String d1;
@CsvBind
private Long u1;
@CsvBind
private Long lt;
@CsvBind
private DeviceUser ref;
//getters and setters
}
```

I want to write the data, stored in the DeviceUser object, into a .csv file.

output should be:
output.csv:
deviceId,6111,1200,deviceId,6111,1200,

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please, write your code from your attempt (even if not working), so people know you don't want just someone to do it for you. Googling I easily found this: http://howtodoinjava.com/3rd-party/parse-read-write-csv-files-opencsv-tutorial/

Comment: below, sol is working fine with ref object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your class add the following method:

```
public String[] toArray() {
    String[] result = new String[6];
    result[0] = this.d1;
    result[1] = this.u2.toString();
    result[2] = this.lt.toString();
    result[3] = this.ref.getd1();
    result[4] = this.ref.getu2().toString();
    result[5] = this.ref.getlt().toString();
    return result;
}
```

And now use the following:

```
 CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("yourfile.csv"), ',');
 // feed in your array (or convert your data to an array)
 writer.writeNext(deviceUser.toArray());
 writer.close();
```

Although it'll work, it's not how you want to do that. For writing objects to files it's better to write JSONs. I would recommend `Google Gson`.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.toJson(obj, new FileWriter("yourfile.csv"));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply
but because of reference, it is printing that object twice.

Comment: is the reference to the object itself or to another object??

Comment: i want , deviceId,6111,1200,deviceId,6111,1200. but is giving, 
deviceId,6111,1200,deviceId,6111,1200,deviceId,6111,1200

Comment: it can be same or different object of same type

Comment: @sachin10 it's not possible. My code prints 6 values. Are you sure you're using it as I wrote?

Comment: @sachin10 please add the code you're trying to run to your question

Comment: @sachin10 mark it as solution then :) You can do so by clicking on a gray tick below the answer score